# Publishing to file system fails *.js *.css *.sitemap Tridion

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I have tridion set up to publish all files except .css .js .sitemap to Database,

Please find below the config

```
<Item typeMapping="Page" itemExtension=".sitemap" cached="false" storageId="defaultFile"/>
<Item typeMapping="Page" itemExtension=".css" cached="false" storageId="defaultFile"/>
<Item typeMapping="Page" itemExtension=".js" cached="false" storageId="defaultFile"/>
<Item typeMapping="Page" cached="false" storageId="defaultDataFile"/>
<Item typeMapping="Binary" storageId="defaultFile" cached="false"/>
<Item typeMapping="Page" cached="false" storageId="defaultDataFile"/>
<Item typeMapping="Metadata" cached="false" storageId="defaultDataFile"/>   `
```

While publishing it failse at `Commiting Deployment` with error

> Phase:Deployment Prepare Commit Phase failed, Unable to prepare transaction: Unable to Store item inide current transaction, Unable to remove data entity, org.hibernate.exceptopn.SQLGrammerException
>   Could not exicute update query,`

Comment: where does `storageId="defaultFile"` point to, is this a valid location on your file system?

Comment: Yes it is a valid location in file system

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was with database connection. I used a database connection which has read only permission,
I updated the connection and it started working